# Files deleted via mtp still consume space

Tags: file-system, file-management, mtp

When I delete a few large files (part of music collection, ~20GB of flac files) during mtp connection (on computer), it disappeared from Android FS, but, according to FS analysis, still consume space.

How to free this space?

FS analysis shows consumed space as "other".
None of visible folders has such big size.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S10e

MTP driver: gvfs-mtp

Comment: still after reboot? for MicroSD cards you can run fsck_msdos -y /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 and delete LOST.DIR afterwards

Comment: @alecxs yes, it persists after reboot. And no, it is phone internal storage.

Comment: adb push [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.31.0-defconfig-multiarch-musl) binary to /data/local/tmp and examine occupied space with ./busybox du -cxhd1 /storage/emulated/0